# Content differs in application.css on different servers

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

We are running production rails application on two different servers. After precompiling the assets on the respective servers the asset digest we get are totally different.

```
application-8d36938ed5deae12e5cc20d3df80db04.css
application-17cc63a0983ee30dda2eb3e8a2403e4b.css
```

On exploring further both the css files had different contents. For the same color rule both css file have different values

For Example:

```
background-color: white; -> in server A
background-color: #fff;  -> in server B
```

This kind of dissimilarities is found in lot of place inside that file.
I examined the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock they are same in both the servers. What would be the reason? Can someone explain?

I guessed the problem is due to the different versions of nodejs in both the machines, cause asset pre-compilation is dependent on nodejs. So we tried tried to get nodejs version on both the machines to same version, even though this error is occuring. What am I missing here?

**UPDATE:**

**Linux versions:**

Server 1:

```
$ cat /etc/debian_version
8.0
```

Server 2:

```
$ cat /etc/debian_version
7.5
```

**NodeJs versions:**

Server 1:

```
$ nodejs -v
v0.10.29
$ dpkg -l | grep nodejs
ii  nodejs                               0.10.29~dfsg-1~bpo70+1        amd64        evented I/O for V8 javascript
```

Server 2:

```
$ nodejs -v
v0.10.29
$ dpkg -l | grep nodejs
ii  nodejs                            0.10.29~dfsg-2                    amd64        evented I/O for V8 javascript
```

**Gemfile.lock:**

Server 1:

```
# Gemfile.lock
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/sporkrb/spork-rails.git
  revision: 0dd45e59d3237b4c8f9efc215b46d9c07072a95e
  specs:
    spork-rails (4.0.0)
      rails (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      spork (>= 1.0rc0)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.0.0)
      actionpack (= 4.0.0)
      mail (~> 2.5.3)
    actionpack (4.0.0)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    activemodel (4.0.0)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
    activerecord (4.0.0)
      activemodel (= 4.0.0)
      activerecord-deprecated_finders (~> 1.0.2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      arel (~> 4.0.0)
    activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.4)
    activesupport (4.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
      minitest (~> 4.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.37)
    addressable (2.4.0)
    amq-protocol (2.0.1)
    arel (4.0.2)
    awesome_print (1.6.1)
    aws-sdk (2.2.12)
      aws-sdk-resources (= 2.2.12)
    aws-sdk-core (2.2.12)
      jmespath (~> 1.0)
    aws-sdk-resources (2.2.12)
      aws-sdk-core (= 2.2.12)
    bcrypt (3.1.10)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.1.5)
      bcrypt (>= 3.1.3)
    beefcake (0.3.7)
    better_errors (2.1.1)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubis (>= 2.6.6)
      rack (>= 0.9.0)
    bloomfilter-rb (2.1.1)
      redis
    bootstrap-sass (3.1.1.1)
      sass (~> 3.2)
    bootstrap-will_paginate (0.0.10)
      will_paginate
    bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails (3.0.0.2)
      momentjs-rails (~> 2.5.0)
    builder (3.1.4)
    bunny (1.4.1)
      amq-protocol (>= 1.9.2)
    capybara (2.5.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    chartkick (1.4.1)
    childprocess (0.5.9)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    chronic (0.10.2)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.1.x)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
    color (1.8)
    crack (0.4.3)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0.0)
    daemons (1.2.3)
    devise (3.5.6)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      responders
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    devise_ldap_authenticatable (0.8.4)
      devise (>= 3.4.1)
      net-ldap (>= 0.3.1, < 0.6.0)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    docile (1.1.5)
    elasticsearch (1.0.15)
      elasticsearch-api (= 1.0.15)
      elasticsearch-transport (= 1.0.15)
    elasticsearch-api (1.0.15)
      multi_json
    elasticsearch-transport (1.0.15)
      faraday
      multi_json
    em-websocket (0.5.1)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.9)
      http_parser.rb (~> 0.6.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.9.1)
    execjs (2.6.0)
    factory_girl (4.5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.5.0)
      factory_girl (~> 4.5.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faraday (0.9.2)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    fastercsv (1.5.5)
    ffi (1.9.10)
    font-awesome-rails (4.5.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.0)
    formatador (0.2.5)
    guard (2.13.0)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (>= 2.7, <= 4.0)
      lumberjack (~> 1.0)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      notiffany (~> 0.0)
      pry (>= 0.9.12)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
      thor (>= 0.18.1)
    guard-compat (1.2.1)
    guard-livereload (2.5.1)
      em-websocket (~> 0.5)
      guard (~> 2.8)
      guard-compat (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.8)
    guard-rspec (4.6.4)
      guard (~> 2.1)
      guard-compat (~> 1.1)
      rspec (>= 2.99.0, < 4.0)
    guard-spork (2.1.0)
      childprocess (>= 0.2.3)
      guard (~> 2.0)
      guard-compat (~> 1.0)
      spork (>= 0.8.4)
    high_voltage (2.2.1)
    hike (1.2.3)
    http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
    httpclient (2.7.1)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    innertube (1.0.2)
    jbuilder (2.4.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jmespath (1.1.3)
    jquery-rails (3.1.4)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.3)
    listen (3.0.5)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
    log4r (1.1.10)
    lumberjack (1.0.10)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    mini_portile2 (2.0.0)
    minitest (4.7.5)
    momentjs-rails (2.5.1)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    mono_logger (1.1.0)
    multi_json (1.11.2)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    mysql (2.9.1)
    nenv (0.2.0)
    net-ldap (0.5.1)
    nokogiri (1.6.7.2)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.0.0.rc2)
    nori (2.6.0)
    notiffany (0.0.8)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
    open4 (1.3.4)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pdf-writer (1.1.8)
      color (>= 1.4.0)
      transaction-simple (~> 1.3)
    polyglot (0.3.5)
    pony (1.11)
      mail (>= 2.0)
    pry (0.10.3)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8.1)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    quiet_assets (1.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
    rack (1.5.5)
    rack-protection (1.5.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.0.0)
      actionmailer (= 4.0.0)
      actionpack (= 4.0.0)
      activerecord (= 4.0.0)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.0.0)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    rails-footnotes (4.1.7)
      rails (>= 3.2)
    railties (4.0.0)
      actionpack (= 4.0.0)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.5.0)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.7)
    rb-inotify (0.9.5)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    redis (3.2.2)
    redis-namespace (1.5.2)
      redis (~> 3.0, >= 3.0.4)
    responders (1.1.2)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 4.2)
    resque (1.25.2)
      mono_logger (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      redis-namespace (~> 1.3)
      sinatra (>= 0.9.2)
      vegas (~> 0.1.2)
    riak-client (1.4.4.1)
      beefcake (~> 0.3.7)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      innertube (~> 1.0.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    rspec (3.4.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.4.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.4.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.4.0)
    rspec-core (3.4.2)
      rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.4.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.4.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
    rspec-rails (3.4.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      rspec-core (~> 3.4.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.4.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.4.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
    rspec-support (3.4.1)
    ruby_protobuf (0.4.11)
    ruport (1.6.3)
      fastercsv
      pdf-writer (= 1.1.8)
    safe_yaml (1.0.4)
    sass (3.4.21)
    sass-rails (5.0.4)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sdoc (0.3.20)
      json (>= 1.1.3)
      rdoc (~> 3.10)
    sequel (4.30.0)
    shellany (0.0.1)
    shoulda-matchers (2.6.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    simple-graphite (2.1.0)
    simplecov (0.11.1)
      docile (~> 1.1.0)
      json (~> 1.8)
      simplecov-html (~> 0.10.0)
    simplecov-html (0.10.0)
    sinatra (1.4.7)
      rack (~> 1.5)
      rack-protection (~> 1.4)
      tilt (>= 1.3, < 3)
    slop (3.6.0)
    spork (1.0.0rc4)
    sprockets (2.11.0)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8)
    sqlite3 (1.3.11)
    term_extraction (0.1.7)
      crack (>= 0.1.6)
    thin (1.6.4)
      daemons (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.0)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    transaction-simple (1.4.0.2)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (0.3.46)
    uglifier (2.7.2)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    vegas (0.1.11)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    voldemort-rb (0.1.9)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.3.1)
      ruby_protobuf (>= 0.3.3)
    warden (1.2.6)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    will_paginate (3.1.0)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  addressable (= 2.4.0)
  awesome_print (= 1.6.1)
  aws-sdk (= 2.2.12)
  bcrypt-ruby (= 3.1.5)
  better_errors (= 2.1.1)
  bloomfilter-rb (= 2.1.1)
  bootstrap-sass (= 3.1.1.1)
  bootstrap-will_paginate (= 0.0.10)
  bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails (~> 3.0.0.1)
  bunny (= 1.4.1)
  capybara (= 2.5.0)
  chartkick (= 1.4.1)
  childprocess (= 0.5.9)
  chronic (= 0.10.2)
  devise (~> 3.5, >= 3.5.6)
  devise_ldap_authenticatable (~> 0.8.4)
  elasticsearch (~> 1.0.2)
  factory_girl_rails (= 4.5.0)
  font-awesome-rails (= 4.5.0.0)
  guard-livereload (= 2.5.1)
  guard-rspec (= 4.6.4)
  guard-spork (= 2.1.0)
  high_voltage (= 2.2.1)
  httpclient (~> 2.6, >= 2.6.0.1)
  jbuilder (= 2.4.0)
  jquery-rails (= 3.1.4)
  log4r (= 1.1.10)
  momentjs-rails (= 2.5.1)
  mysql (= 2.9.1)
  net-ldap (~> 0.5.1)
  nori (~> 2.6)
  open4 (= 1.3.4)
  pony (= 1.11)
  quiet_assets (= 1.1.0)
  rails (= 4.0.0)
  rails-footnotes (= 4.1.7)
  resque (= 1.25.2)
  riak-client (= 1.4.4.1)
  rspec-rails (= 3.4.0)
  ruport (= 1.6.3)
  sass-rails (= 5.0.4)
  sdoc (= 0.3.20)
  sequel (= 4.30.0)
  shoulda-matchers (= 2.6.2)
  simple-graphite (= 2.1.0)
  simplecov (= 0.11.1)
  spork-rails!
  sprockets (= 2.11.0)
  sqlite3 (= 1.3.11)
  term_extraction (= 0.1.7)
  thin (= 1.6.4)
  turbolinks (= 2.5.3)
  uglifier (= 2.7.2)
  voldemort-rb (= 0.1.9)
```

Server 2:

```
# Gemfile.lock
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/sporkrb/spork-rails.git
  revision: 0dd45e59d3237b4c8f9efc215b46d9c07072a95e
  specs:
    spork-rails (4.0.0)
      rails (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      spork (>= 1.0rc0)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.0.0)
      actionpack (= 4.0.0)
      mail (~> 2.5.3)
    actionpack (4.0.0)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    activemodel (4.0.0)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
    activerecord (4.0.0)
      activemodel (= 4.0.0)
      activerecord-deprecated_finders (~> 1.0.2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      arel (~> 4.0.0)
    activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.4)
    activesupport (4.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
      minitest (~> 4.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.37)
    addressable (2.4.0)
    amq-protocol (2.0.1)
    arel (4.0.2)
    awesome_print (1.6.1)
    aws-sdk (2.2.12)
      aws-sdk-resources (= 2.2.12)
    aws-sdk-core (2.2.12)
      jmespath (~> 1.0)
    aws-sdk-resources (2.2.12)
      aws-sdk-core (= 2.2.12)
    bcrypt (3.1.10)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.1.5)
      bcrypt (>= 3.1.3)
    beefcake (0.3.7)
    better_errors (2.1.1)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubis (>= 2.6.6)
      rack (>= 0.9.0)
    bloomfilter-rb (2.1.1)
      redis
    bootstrap-sass (3.1.1.1)
      sass (~> 3.2)
    bootstrap-will_paginate (0.0.10)
      will_paginate
    bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails (3.0.0.2)
      momentjs-rails (~> 2.5.0)
    builder (3.1.4)
    bunny (1.4.1)
      amq-protocol (>= 1.9.2)
    capybara (2.5.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    chartkick (1.4.1)
    childprocess (0.5.9)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    chronic (0.10.2)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.1.x)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
    color (1.8)
    crack (0.4.3)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0.0)
    daemons (1.2.3)
    devise (3.5.6)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      responders
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    devise_ldap_authenticatable (0.8.4)
      devise (>= 3.4.1)
      net-ldap (>= 0.3.1, < 0.6.0)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    docile (1.1.5)
    elasticsearch (1.0.15)
      elasticsearch-api (= 1.0.15)
      elasticsearch-transport (= 1.0.15)
    elasticsearch-api (1.0.15)
      multi_json
    elasticsearch-transport (1.0.15)
      faraday
      multi_json
    em-websocket (0.5.1)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.9)
      http_parser.rb (~> 0.6.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.9.1)
    execjs (2.6.0)
    factory_girl (4.5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.5.0)
      factory_girl (~> 4.5.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faraday (0.9.2)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    fastercsv (1.5.5)
    ffi (1.9.10)
    font-awesome-rails (4.5.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.0)
    formatador (0.2.5)
    guard (2.13.0)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (>= 2.7, <= 4.0)
      lumberjack (~> 1.0)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      notiffany (~> 0.0)
      pry (>= 0.9.12)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
      thor (>= 0.18.1)
    guard-compat (1.2.1)
    guard-livereload (2.5.1)
      em-websocket (~> 0.5)
      guard (~> 2.8)
      guard-compat (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.8)
    guard-rspec (4.6.4)
      guard (~> 2.1)
      guard-compat (~> 1.1)
      rspec (>= 2.99.0, < 4.0)
    guard-spork (2.1.0)
      childprocess (>= 0.2.3)
      guard (~> 2.0)
      guard-compat (~> 1.0)
      spork (>= 0.8.4)
    high_voltage (2.2.1)
    hike (1.2.3)
    http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
    httpclient (2.7.1)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    innertube (1.0.2)
    jbuilder (2.4.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jmespath (1.1.3)
    jquery-rails (3.1.4)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.3)
    listen (3.0.5)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
    log4r (1.1.10)
    lumberjack (1.0.10)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    mini_portile2 (2.0.0)
    minitest (4.7.5)
    momentjs-rails (2.5.1)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    mono_logger (1.1.0)
    multi_json (1.11.2)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    mysql (2.9.1)
    nenv (0.2.0)
    net-ldap (0.5.1)
    nokogiri (1.6.7.2)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.0.0.rc2)
    nori (2.6.0)
    notiffany (0.0.8)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
    open4 (1.3.4)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pdf-writer (1.1.8)
      color (>= 1.4.0)
      transaction-simple (~> 1.3)
    polyglot (0.3.5)
    pony (1.11)
      mail (>= 2.0)
    pry (0.10.3)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8.1)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    quiet_assets (1.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
    rack (1.5.5)
    rack-protection (1.5.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.0.0)
      actionmailer (= 4.0.0)
      actionpack (= 4.0.0)
      activerecord (= 4.0.0)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.0.0)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    rails-footnotes (4.1.7)
      rails (>= 3.2)
    railties (4.0.0)
      actionpack (= 4.0.0)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.5.0)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.7)
    rb-inotify (0.9.5)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    redis (3.2.2)
    redis-namespace (1.5.2)
      redis (~> 3.0, >= 3.0.4)
    responders (1.1.2)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 4.2)
    resque (1.25.2)
      mono_logger (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      redis-namespace (~> 1.3)
      sinatra (>= 0.9.2)
      vegas (~> 0.1.2)
    riak-client (1.4.4.1)
      beefcake (~> 0.3.7)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      innertube (~> 1.0.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    rspec (3.4.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.4.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.4.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.4.0)
    rspec-core (3.4.2)
      rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.4.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.4.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
    rspec-rails (3.4.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      rspec-core (~> 3.4.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.4.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.4.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
    rspec-support (3.4.1)
    ruby_protobuf (0.4.11)
    ruport (1.6.3)
      fastercsv
      pdf-writer (= 1.1.8)
    safe_yaml (1.0.4)
    sass (3.4.21)
    sass-rails (5.0.4)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sdoc (0.3.20)
      json (>= 1.1.3)
      rdoc (~> 3.10)
    sequel (4.30.0)
    shellany (0.0.1)
    shoulda-matchers (2.6.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    simple-graphite (2.1.0)
    simplecov (0.11.1)
      docile (~> 1.1.0)
      json (~> 1.8)
      simplecov-html (~> 0.10.0)
    simplecov-html (0.10.0)
    sinatra (1.4.7)
      rack (~> 1.5)
      rack-protection (~> 1.4)
      tilt (>= 1.3, < 3)
    slop (3.6.0)
    spork (1.0.0rc4)
    sprockets (2.11.0)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8)
    sqlite3 (1.3.11)
    term_extraction (0.1.7)
      crack (>= 0.1.6)
    thin (1.6.4)
      daemons (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.0)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    transaction-simple (1.4.0.2)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (0.3.46)
    uglifier (2.7.2)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    vegas (0.1.11)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    voldemort-rb (0.1.9)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.3.1)
      ruby_protobuf (>= 0.3.3)
    warden (1.2.6)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    will_paginate (3.1.0)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  addressable (= 2.4.0)
  awesome_print (= 1.6.1)
  aws-sdk (= 2.2.12)
  bcrypt-ruby (= 3.1.5)
  better_errors (= 2.1.1)
  bloomfilter-rb (= 2.1.1)
  bootstrap-sass (= 3.1.1.1)
  bootstrap-will_paginate (= 0.0.10)
  bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails (~> 3.0.0.1)
  bunny (= 1.4.1)
  capybara (= 2.5.0)
  chartkick (= 1.4.1)
  childprocess (= 0.5.9)
  chronic (= 0.10.2)
  devise (~> 3.5, >= 3.5.6)
  devise_ldap_authenticatable (~> 0.8.4)
  elasticsearch (~> 1.0.2)
  factory_girl_rails (= 4.5.0)
  font-awesome-rails (= 4.5.0.0)
  guard-livereload (= 2.5.1)
  guard-rspec (= 4.6.4)
  guard-spork (= 2.1.0)
  high_voltage (= 2.2.1)
  httpclient (~> 2.6, >= 2.6.0.1)
  jbuilder (= 2.4.0)
  jquery-rails (= 3.1.4)
  log4r (= 1.1.10)
  momentjs-rails (= 2.5.1)
  mysql (= 2.9.1)
  net-ldap (~> 0.5.1)
  nori (~> 2.6)
  open4 (= 1.3.4)
  pony (= 1.11)
  quiet_assets (= 1.1.0)
  rails (= 4.0.0)
  rails-footnotes (= 4.1.7)
  resque (= 1.25.2)
  riak-client (= 1.4.4.1)
  rspec-rails (= 3.4.0)
  ruport (= 1.6.3)
  sass-rails (= 5.0.4)
  sdoc (= 0.3.20)
  sequel (= 4.30.0)
  shoulda-matchers (= 2.6.2)
  simple-graphite (= 2.1.0)
  simplecov (= 0.11.1)
  spork-rails!
  sprockets (= 2.11.0)
  sqlite3 (= 1.3.11)
  term_extraction (= 0.1.7)
  thin (= 1.6.4)
  turbolinks (= 2.5.3)
  uglifier (= 2.7.2)
  voldemort-rb (= 0.1.9)
```

Comment: Clearly your deployment process does not use the same built codebase.  That's about the best answer you can get without access to your actual source-control, build and deployment servers.  Your processes should be logging what they're doing, so check and compare the logs to see what is being built and deployed.  We really can't do that for you.

Comment: Deployment process is good and the codebase is same, I can vouch for that. All the rest of the css manifest list dashboard.css and layout.css are same between the two servers just that one application.css is giving troubles.

Comment: As I said, with no other details, and without access to your entire source-control/build/deploy process, nobody here could possibly have a clue what is happening.  Clearly the deployment and/or build process is NOT good or this wouldn't be happening.  I'd also make sure you don't have any caching in a proxy or CDN but you haven't mentioned that as part of the situation.

Comment: Made an update. Please let me know what more details needed?

Comment: have you tried rake assets:clean

Comment: Are you using `.scss` / `.sass`?

Comment: I have tried rake assets:clean, rake assets:clobber everything. I'm using .scss files

Comment: @JimGarrison I guess the details that I've given now is good enough.